# Android Developer Account Payment from a different persons credit card

Tags: android, credit-card

I am trying to sign up for an Android developer account, costs $25.  Due to some unwise choices many years ago I am without a credit card.  My significant other is more than happy to help out here.  So I go to create the account, it accepts my payment then brings me to a screen with this message: "I agree and I am willing to associate my credit card and account registration above with the Android Market Developer Distribution Agreement."  The name in the box that appears is the name of my significant other and not myself.  From what I can tell then the developer account will be forever linked to that person and not me even though it is my google account.  Is this correct?  It also turns out I will be getting a credit card in 2-3 weeks but cannot wait that long.  So would it be possible to pay it now and change credit cards later?  It seems hard to believe Google would require the credit card for anything more than payment but from what I can tell they register the developer side forever under the credit card owner.  Someone correct me if I'm wrong before I waste $25 or bind someone else to my developer account by accident.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question - it is about google's terms and conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you get a prepaid credit card?  My neighborhood bank offers prepaid gift credit cards for purchase, many places do.  The critical bit is that the card must be valid for on-line purchases.  Not all prepaid credit cards are. With my local bank you have to register the card to get it activated for on-line purchases.  Read the fine print finely.

Comment: Good tip, I wasn't even aware you could get a pre paid credit card.  I will have to talk to my bank.  However if they say it'll take 2-3 weeks to arrive then I'd be in the same boat now. However this seems like a fair solution, I will go to my bank tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Lots of places offer them.  Western Union, Walmart, etc.  Do a google search.  Just remember to check for the on-line purchase thing.

Comment: I believe in Canada my only choice is a 7-11.  There are 3 Wal Marts in this city but I don't think Wal Mart in Canada has pre paid credit cards.  It still seems weird to me how the dev account uses the credit card used for any purpose other than payment.